# Cross Apply in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my sql in SQL Server. How can I achieve this in MySQL?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM (SELECT  personal.*
CROSS APPLY
  (
     SELECT  TOP 1 educ_attain.school
     FROM    educ_attain
     WHERE   personal.empno = educ_attain.empno
  ) educ
WHERE personal.status = 'ACTIVE'
) as num
```

My goal is to exclude employees who doesn't have a record in educ_attain. I have tried using sub-query but still returning employees with no record.

Comment: Some employees have multiple records in educ_attain.

Comment: Your code is not syntactically correct and `personal` is not defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try any of these following-

```
SELECT * 
FROM personal
INNER JOIN educ_attain
ON personal.empno = educ_attain.empno
WHERE personal.status = 'ACTIVE'
```

OR

```
SELECT * 
FROM personal
WHERE empno IN
(
    SELECT DISTINCT empno FROM educ_attain
)
AND status = 'ACTIVE'
```

To get count - Just use SELECT COUNT(*) for any of the above query.

Answer (score 0):

`Not Exists`, employees do not have record in eductable then show

```
select * from
employee e
where not exists   
(
select 1 from eductable t
   on e.emp_id = t.emp_id
)
```